# Looking for background panorama plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to find a plugin, or a line of code that could help me achieve an effect on the background image (the scrolling following the mouse):

http://teddavis.org/

Does anyone think there's a similar way to do that in jQuery so i can **add some easing** and make this smoother.

Or even, if you know how to put easing on that very code, i'd be grateful too!

Thanks in advance!

Thai

Answer (score 2):

If you check the source of the page you will notice:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 

    // Simple follow the mouse script
    var divName = 'pano'; // div that is to follow the mouse
                           // (must be position:absolute)
    var offX = -5500;          // X offset from mouse position
    var offY = -000;          // Y offset from mouse position

    function mouseX(evt) {
        if (!evt) evt = window.event;
        if (evt.pageX) return evt.pageX;
        else if (evt.clientX) return evt.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ?  document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
        else return 0;
    }
    function mouseY(evt) {
        if (!evt) evt = window.event;
        if (evt.pageY) return evt.pageY;
        else if (evt.clientY) return evt.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop); 
        else return 0;
    }
    function follow(evt) {
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var obj = document.getElementById(divName).style;
            obj.visibility = 'visible';
            obj.left = (parseInt(mouseX(evt)*-4)+offX) + 'px';
        }
    }
    document.onmousemove = follow;      
    function stopscroll(){
        document.onmousemove = stop;
    }

</script>
```

seems to be very simple to implement. Just make sure that the variable divName refers to your image or DIV

Comment: Thanks Rdpi!

I had seen that. My question is about adding easing to it!